# How do you not smash the laboratory wall?

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

Is it possible to not smash the laboratory wall for the achievement **Another Way In**?

> **Another Way In**
>   Start a game without breaking the laboratory wall.

Comment: Are you referring to before the start of each run? To my knowledge this is not possible, but I have no played the game in a long time so this may have changed.

Comment: There is an achievement that is gained when you enter the lab without breaking the wall.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Jetpack Joyride wikia](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Another_Way_In):

> Buy gadgets until you can buy the “Free Ride” gadget. Once equipped, play the game until you start with the **Crazy Freaking Teleporter** .

Here's a demonstration video:

Answer (score -5):

To not smash the wall, **get the upgrade/item thing Random Vehicle at Start or whatever it's called**, and hope for the best! :)

Comment: Why so much hate on my answer? I answered his question, and all I get is hate from the community.

Comment: Words like "thing" and "whatever it is called" put this answer to shame. Be crystal clear about what you're saying. And if you can link any source, that would be even better

Comment: It's very broad."random thing at start" doesn't tell me what it is.